# Highlight by row in gt

Tags: r, gt

I am trying to see if gt can highlight by rows the max value *in that row*. So take this dataset:

```r
dat <- iris |>
    dplyr::group_by(Species) |>
    dplyr::summarise(
        Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length),
        Sepal.Width = mean(Sepal.Width),
        Petal.Length = mean(Petal.Length),
        Petal.Width = mean(Petal.Width)
    ) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = -Species,
    names_to = "Measurement",
    values_to = "Value"
  ) |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    names_from = Species,
    values_from = Value
  ) 

dat
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   Measurement  setosa versicolor virginica
#>   <chr>         <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 Sepal.Length  5.01        5.94      6.59
#> 2 Sepal.Width   3.43        2.77      2.97
#> 3 Petal.Length  1.46        4.26      5.55
#> 4 Petal.Width   0.246       1.33      2.03
```

Now I know I can highlight by column like this:

```r
gt(dat) |>
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_borders(
        color = "#000000",
        weight = px(2)
      )
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = setosa,
      rows = setosa == max(setosa)
    )
  )
```

which produces:

[image]

But if there any way to highlight the max by row? Basically here I want a box drawn around which species has the max of the measurements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list of `cells_body` :

```
gt(dat) |>
  tab_style(style = list(cell_borders(color = "#000000",
                                      weight = px(2))),
            locations = lapply(
              1:nrow(dat),
              FUN =
                function(rowNumber) {
                  cells_body(columns = which.max(dat[rowNumber, ]),
                             rows = rowNumber)
                }
            ))
```